# Does the Pokemon, Emolga, evolve?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

I have a Level 40 Emolga in Pokemon Black, but it hasn't evolved yet. How do I make it evolve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emolga doesn't evolve.

Source: [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Emolga#Evolution)

Comment: That's a bummer :|

Comment: Yea, still a pretty neat pokemon though. Neat typing with the electric/flying. If you want a similar pokemon (that does evolve), I'd suggest a http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tynamo_(Pok%C3%A9mon)

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the suggestion. So that's where Elektrik comes from.

Comment: Saw this on reddit and then this question was bumped, clearly a sign. http://i.imgur.com/Ei9KG.jpg

Comment: @Rapida Omg Evolva is Batmon !!! NaNaNaNaNaNaNa

Comment: if you paid any attention to the recent world championships you'd see just how much damage a single stage pikachu clone can cause